# Symfony SQL sometimes no results

Tags: sql, oracle, symfony

I've got an sql which should give me a list, but sometimes the result will be empty. It happens randomly. There is no change in user, version, or anything. Just another request which will sometimes be empty.

There is an Database Table which has a trigger to historize the values.
If a new Line is inserted then in the history table a new line is created to. For the new table there is a "validFrom" columns which will be set to sysdate.
If updated the old line will be set with an "validUntil" and a new line is inserted.
This Table has an index on SUB_ID.

The table is no materialized view, or view. Just a plain table.

SQL

```
SELECT h.ID, h.SUB_ID
FROM history h
WHERE 1=1
AND h.SUB_ID = :subId
                    AND (
                        1=1
                        AND ( 
                            TO_DATE(:startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= h.VALIDFROM
                            AND TO_DATE(:startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= NVL(h.VALIDUNTIL,sysdate)
                        ) OR ( 
                            TO_DATE(:startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= h.VALIDFROM
                            AND TO_DATE(:endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= NVL(h.VALIDUNTIL,sysdate)
                        ) OR ( 
                            TO_DATE(:endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= h.VALIDFROM
                            AND TO_DATE(:endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= NVL(h.VALIDUNTIL,sysdate)
                        )
                    )
```

PHP

```
$validFrom = new Datetime();
$validUntil = new Datetime();
$query = $this->db->prepare($query);
$query->bindValue('subId', 20180101123456789, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue('startDate', $validFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue('endDate', $validUntil->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

$result will sometimes be empty, and sometimes there will be results. My only workaround is to try it up to 500 times, then i'll get an result.
I've tried with a sleep(1) too, but its still random when the result will be null. Only the script will take way longer.

If i try an plsql block with 500 tries, then i'll get 500 times a result.

Someone an idea why this is happening?

Comment: did you check that $query is not null ?? may be you missed your database connection

Comment: So are you trying to find results with startDate AND endDate both == the current time?

Comment: @Gar Query ist not empty. Always filled, but nothing returned. Code is noch changed, just run multiple times. sometimes there is a result, sometimes not.

Comment: @ArleighHix not exacly startDate and endDate are boundaries. There could be valid results which begin before, but are valid in between, then there are thos which are only between and those that start between and end after.
The date selection works for many other tables, just this one throws sometimes no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of testing different scenarios i've found the cause.
This is caused because oracle sysdate can be older than php datetime.

One would expect:

```
php new Datetime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') = 2019-06-05 12:55:00
oracle to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= 2019-06-05 12:55:00
```

But if the oracle server lacks behind for the server time, then it could be

```
php new Datetime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') = 2019-06-05 12:55:00
oracle to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <=> 2019-06-05 12:55:00
```

Since the oracle sysdate cannot only be bigger, but also smaller, some strange things can happen. Therefore i changed the sysdate comparrison to "sysdate+1" like:

```
NVL(h.VALIDUNTIL,sysdate+1)
```

Since it is a replacement for a NULL Value it is possible to be in the future and still result in the wanted results.